# Between 2014 and 2019 - Which countries are known to have charged people with criminal offenses for finding traces of illegal substances upon entry?

Tags: legal, drugs

*Time restriction is applied simply to remove "old" results that may not be relevant anymore, and to ensure this question is not made outdated by the passage of time or changes to varies countries laws.*

Based on this article: http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/7234786.stm

> (Written 2006) Meanwhile, a Swiss national is serving a four-year jail term after three poppy seeds from a bread roll he ate at Heathrow airport were found on his clothes.

With similar cases more recently: https://www.buzzfeed.com/ishmaeldaro/canadian-woman-jailed-abu-dhabi

> (Written 2016) Guards searched her bags and found a small amount of marijuana, no more than some "loose flakes," in her backpack, Augustyn's mother Joanne told BuzzFeed News.

---

Which countries are known publicly, to have charged somebody with a criminal offense for the possession of illicit substances based only on traces of the substance being found - between 2014 and 2019 *(last 5 years from the question's post date)*?

*To be clear, a "trace" here would be an amount of substance that is detectible on a person, but by common sense could not have been used by the person any further. For example, the 3 poppy seeds above or traces of cocaine that are found on bank notes. Finding traces, that lead to a "real" find such as a "useable" quantity of e.g. cocaine would not count here.*

*Criminal charges in this question means having been charged with committing the crime, whether the case fell through in court or not. The person did not need to be found guilty to apply.*

*Also the "illegal substances" in question; are anything the country deems to be illegal. The important aspect is that only a trace-amount was found.*

Please ensure any given answer has at least one example case given for each country. This question requires substantiated information, as such speculation or gut-feel is not sufficient.

Comment: What does this question have to do with travel? Last I checked we don't have commercially viable time machines so there's no way it can be relevant for contemporary travel.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Honestly, the article linked was found through a comment to a question here - and instantly made me worry about travelling in general terms; which locations have a reputation for this. That said, I wasn't sure whether this should be here, history or law - and figured posting closest to the source the inspired it would be safest (and see it migrated if needed). The time restriction was to avoid this being open-ended, so it does have a cannonically correct answer; but realistically the implication is "..so I can be wary when travelling to these countries in the next decade"

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Last time I checked, the calendar did say 2019. Also if someone got arrested in 2017, it would be wise to consider avoiding the same behavior even if it’s 2020.

Comment: @Bilkokuya Apart from the news item you’ve linked to, what research have you done yourself?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s too broad and - even if a list could be compiled without onerous research - the fact that a particular country hasn’t historically taken this approach doesn’t necessarily indicate it wouldn’t.

Comment: @Traveller In terms of research, I'm afraid I've only been able to go as far as general purpose online searches - which has found multiple other cases of people arrested in UAE, but none elsewhere (all other cases I've found involved quantities large enough for personal use at minimum). I disagree that this question is "too broad" - it's well defined and has a correct answer. But I don't dispute that it may not be a good fit here (i.e. "blatantly off-topic"). Also, I disagree that difficulty should factor in - if it's "not worth" answering, it's should just remain unanswered.

Comment: @RomanOdaisky -- Sure, 2019 would be helpful if over-broad. But not 1999. Or even 2018. Also 2019 is only a few months old and it's asking "has *given* a criminal sentence" which indicates that someone has been caught and charged.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas If changing the date range would be more useful - I'm happy to do so. The range I picked was simply that I wanted to exclude any extremely old results, without making it so narrow that there was no related incidents at all. If there's a date range you feel is more appropriate for current travel - please feel free to just recommend it or edit it in. I'll also change "convicted" to "charged" as it's probably irrelevant whether the person was successfully convicted - both would put me off travelling.

Comment: Current year is the only useful year. Accepting data from the previous year along with an indication that law/practice has not changed is sufficient to narrow it down to being useful. Of course, the question will only be useful for the current year, at that point. Furthermore it doesn't address the fact that there are no geographical restrictions on the question and I'm sure we already have questions/answers about specific localities (Indonesia comes to mind, possibly the Netherlands.)

Comment: And then in addition, you've listed "illegal substances." What all does that even cover? Marijuana is not illegal where I live but carries a really stiff sentence in Indonesia. Some medications can be obtained under prescriptions in country A but are completely illegal in country B. Really this would be a useful question if you could do it like "Are there consequences to carrying <some specific substance> on my person/luggage when travelling or transiting through <some specific location>?"

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas First, thanks for the help improving this question. For the "illegal substances", this was purposefully broad - in that it's any substance the relevant country decided is illegal. The key motivation for this question was not wanting to be caught in a country for traces *that I had no knowledge of having* - so narrowing it down to specific substances defeats that for me (but I understand why you want it). For "current year" would that be Mar2018-Mar2019?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas "Current year is the only useful year": I disagree strongly.  Laws and policies can change at any time.  The chance that they've changed since any incident is higher for an older incident, but it's pretty low even for an incident five years ago.  And it's not zero even for an incident last month.

Comment: @phoog I've edited the timescale to "last 5 years" (2014-2019) based on what you've said. My personal feeling is also that anything older may be less directly relevant, but anything in the last 5 years is fresh enough to cause concerns for current travel.

Comment: In what universe are poppy seeds an illicit substance under any sane code of law?

Comment: @Martha poppy seeds themselves are not a substance, but they (can?) contain trace amounts of opioid compounds.  Opium is, after all, made from poppies.  Try an internet search for `opioid traces in poppy seeds` or something like that.

Comment: While the question might be a bit broad (there are after all over 200 countries with unique legislation in the world), but still, I think it is a highly relevant question for a travel forum. As the examples shown in his link, anyone, even perfectly innocent people, appear to be able to easily get jailed in Dubai. People therefore need to know what risks they take when traveling somewhere or transferring through somewhere.

Comment: @Bilkokuya would that include the Dutch woman traveling to Egypt with a box of Naproxen for her husband who was in a hotel there with severe back pain who was arrested when passing customs in Egypt for possession of narcotics? Turns out Naproxen which is an OTC painkiller in the Netherlands is prescription-only in Egypt and therefore was illegal for her to possess.

Comment: @jwenting it would include having traces of naproxen - say you'd taken some and some of its dust/chalkiness was left on your skin or clothes. But if you had an entire pill - that would be a usable amount so doesn't qualify.